# how to detect what bluetooth device audio is coming out of

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth, avaudiosession

I have two BluetoothHFP bluetooth devices connected to my iPad(bluetoothA2DP and bluetoothLE) and I need to detect which one is currently getting the audio. Below is the code I am using to detect what bluetooth is available :

```
let currentRoute = audioSession.currentRoute
 for description in currentRoute.outputs {
                        if convertFromAVAudioSessionPort(description.portType) == convertFromAVAudioSessionPort(AVAudioSession.Port.bluetoothA2DP) {
                            //Do Something
                            break
                        }else if convertFromAVAudioSessionPort(description.portType) == convertFromAVAudioSessionPort(AVAudioSession.Port.bluetoothHFP) {
                            //Do Something
                            break
                        }else if convertFromAVAudioSessionPort(description.portType) == convertFromAVAudioSessionPort(AVAudioSession.Port.bluetoothLE){
                            //Do Something
                            break
                        }
                    }
```

What can I use to find out what one of the BluetoothHFP devices is currently getting audio?

Answer (score 1):

You can distinguish between ports of the same type using `description.portName` and `description.uid`. Note that the name is not promised to be unique (it comes from the device). The UID is system-assigned and is not promised to be stable. It's only promised to be consistent with the `owningPortUID` property, and will be unique at any given time.

It happens to be true currently (iOS 13) that the UID is based on the hardware MAC address, and is stable. It's in the format `aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff-tacl` (the MAC address followed by `-tacl`). This has been true for a long time. I've been using this fact since at least iOS 8, and it's very likely it's been true as long as AVAudioSession has been around. But it's not promised, and is exactly the kind of thing that Apple has been known to change without notice.

Comment: Do you know what's the `-tacl`' stands for? Because sometimes I get another suffix `-tsco`.

Comment: I don't. I assume it's identifying the type of radio in some way.